# CDI ambiguous dependency when adding @Named qualifier to existing bean via @Produces

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, managed-bean, named

I have a CDI bean implementation in a dependency jar file:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService {
  public String doSomething() {...}
}
```

In my webapp, I want to access that service via EL Expression, therefore I have to give it a `@Named` annotation. But I cannot add the annotation on the `MyService` implementation because I don't have the rights to change that code.

Therefore I tried creating a producer like

```
public class MyServiceProducer {
  @Inject MyService myService;

  @Produces @Named("myService")
  public MyService produceNamedInstance() {
    return myService;
  }
}
```

This results in a

> WELD-001409 - ambiguous dependency for type MyService with qualifiers @Default
>       ...
>       Possible dependencies:
>       - Managed Bean [class ...MyService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
>       - Producer Method [myService] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declared as [...]

How can I add a `@Named` annotation without touching the original source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is referring to the `@Inject MyService`. You basically defined a second bean via `@Produces MyService` which is *also* injectable as `MyService`, but you didn't make clear which one exactly you meant to inject via `@Inject`. So CDI got confused and throws this ambiguous dependency error.

Instead of creating another producer for an already auto-produced bean, you should just extend the existing bean and then name it.

```
@Named("myService")
public class MyNamedService extends MyService {
    //
}
```

Noted should be that the [scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) is already [`@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), so you don't need to re-define it.