# @Produces cause Bean name ambiguous

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, cdi

I working with jee and wildfly for few days now i have problem. I created something like this:

```
@Stateless
public class BookService {

@EJB
private BookDao bookDao;

public void addBook(Book book) {
    bookDao.saveBook(book);
}

public Optional<Book> getBookById(Long id) {
    return bookDao.getBookById(id);
}

public void updateBook(Book book) {
    bookDao.updateBook(book);
}

@Produces
@Named("books")
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    return bookDao.getAllBooks();
}
}
```

Next I tryied to use `#{books}` in jsf but i got exception:

> 2017-05-23 08:49:07,447] Artifact ear:ear: Error during artifact
>   deployment. See server log for details.
>
> [2017-05-23 08:49:07,448] Artifact ear:ear: java.lang.Exception:
>   {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Lab6.ear\".WeldStartService" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"Lab6.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start
>   service
>
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name books resolves to beans:
>
> - Producer Method [List] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Named public
>     app.service.BookService.getAllBooks()],
> - Producer Method [List] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Named public
>     app.service.BookService.getAllBooks()]"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required
>     services that are not installed:" =>
>     ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"Lab6.ear\".WeldStartService"],"WFLYCTL0180:
>     Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}

What is the source of problem.

Comment: Please share information on your deployment structure. I suppose I'll be EAR and you have some dependency twice resulting in two identical producers. Make double sure that the `BookService` is on one place in your deployment only.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you have built your EAR file components incorrectly:

- the EJB jar is in the EAR file itself;
- the EJB jar is also in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR file

This will give you two copies of the same bean.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that you have 2 beans of type Book. To clarify see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982422/cdi-ambiguous-dependency-with-produces-why) here, how the Class and the producer are two beens with the same name.
 And here another example of the same tipycall [mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391001/cdi-ambiguous-dependency-when-adding-named-qualifier-to-existing-bean-via-prod). Check them both.
 You have another bean with the name `books` soomewhere in your code

Comment: Same problem, nothing changed

Comment: I updated the anwer, where in your code do you have another bean called books? maybe a producer or class or consumer?